# Proof of an inequality involving $(N-1)!$

Tags: inequality, products, infinite-product

How is it possible to prove the following inequality?
$$\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^N\left(\dfrac{k^3+k+1}{k^2(k+1)}\right)^\dfrac{1}{N}\ge\left(\frac{1}{N+1}\right)^\dfrac{1}{N}-\left(\dfrac{1}{N^2(N-1)!}\right)^\dfrac{1}{N}$$
I found the equal holds for $N\to\infty$, but I'm unable to verify analytically the inequality even if numerically it holds. Thanks.

Comment: I don't really see a reason to phrase this in terms of $\Gamma(N)$. You're always using integers, so $\Gamma(N)=(N-1)!$.

Comment: @Semiclassical: It's only a different way to write the same thing, I think.

Comment: Well, that the title makes it look like special functions problem at first glance when it's really not. Plus $N \Gamma (N)=N!$, so using $\Gamma$ makes the second expression clunkier.

Comment: @Semiclassical: Ok. I accepted your suggestion and I changed the title and the content.. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is true even in the stronger form:
$$\prod_{k=1}^{N}\frac{k^3+k+1}{k^2(k+1)}>\frac{1}{N+1},\tag{1}$$
since:
$$\frac{k^3+k+1}{k^2(k+1)}>\frac{k}{k+1},\tag{2}$$
so:
$$\prod_{k=1}^{N}\frac{k^3+k+1}{k^2(k+1)}>\prod_{k=1}^{N}\frac{k}{k+1}=\frac{1}{N+1}.$$